# google sheets sumifs with range or named range as criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to sum all the values for the items defined in the `NameRange`, using `SUMIF`: `=SUMIF(E1:E10,D1:D10,NamedRange)`

So I would expect to have `1+3+7+8+10 =`**`29`**, basically all in yellow.

But my result is 0. What do I do wrong?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S9wjWC2QcLc5cScLw_D26NP3vhIl5iKYYkyYyYIPNSE/edit#gid=0) is an editable example

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(G2:G11;NamedRange;H2:H11))`

The result is auto-axpanded row with sums by named range elements "A, B, C, D".

Next step is to use sum:

`=sum(ArrayFormula(SUMIF(G2:G11;NamedRange;H2:H11)))`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna work I'm afraid. But see if this does:

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(D1:D10, join("|", NamedRange)), E1:E10)
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  I guess there is no way to use `SUMIF` with a range. It was much shorter and clear. Thanks